# Storing Excel Rows in List<Range> for later insertion into different workbook

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I am splitting one large spreadsheet into many (100's) smaller spreadsheet.  My approach is to store the rows of the source spreadsheet in a list:

```
List<Range> ranges = new List<Range>();
Workbook book = xl.Workbooks.Add("path to book");
Worksheet sheet = book.sheets[1];
for (int r = 1; r <= sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count; r++)
{
    ranges.Add((Range)sheet.Rows[r]);
}
book.Close();

......
Workbook book2 = xl.Workbooks.Add();
Worksheet sheet2 = book2.sheets[1];
for (int r2 = 0; r2 <= ranges.Count; r2++)
{
   Range row = (Range)ranges[r2]; //
   sheet2.rows[r2+1].Value2 = row;  //fails; 
       //querying in debug, the properties of row all throw an exception
       //queryying sheet.rows[r2+1] expands as expected
}
```

If you see where my error is please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

I think after you close the first source book, you can no longer use the range references you've taken from it. So move `book.Close()` to the end of your snippet. Your upper bound for the for second loop should just be `<` not `<=`.

```
for (int r2 = 0; r2 < ranges.Count; r2++)
{
    ranges[r2].Copy();               
    sheet2.Paste(sheet2.Rows[r2+1]);        
}
```